# Connect to the WPA2 WiFi network using C++ DBus Connman

Tags: c++, dbus, connman

Is it possible to connect to the protected network by its's SSID and password using C++ DBus library?

I could not find any similar code examples over the internet. I want to do something very similar to [this](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/examples/python/dbus/add-wifi-psk-connection.py), but preferably in C++, and without using the Network manager package because my Linux OS has the Connman package.

Any suitable code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it using the Glib DBus bindings. Code (bigger part) is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74548944/14628838).